# Finder launch and quit after booting

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, mojave, macos

I've started noticing that, after booting and launching all app that was on at the time of shut down, finder simply quit after ~10 sec and I have to turn it on manually. I didn't recall this issue before Mojave (but maybe it was already like that, I barely turn off my laptop - just closing it).

It doesn't seems to crash as there is no warning like "finder quit unexpectedly" or anything...

When opening console after finder quit, this output appear :

```
[ApplicationManager statusChangedForApplication:] | In status changed, finder quit, calling to get number of foreground apps
```

Disk utility check says everything's fine, and I just did a clean install as my MBP crashed during last update.

What could be the cause of Finder quitting after launching all app ?

*MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) version 10.14.4 (18E226)*

EDIT :

I find out that when I open pCloud, Finder quit (but still not crash)

Console output :

```
[GUIApplicationLogout loadProccessesToQuitArray] | Checking app: pCloudFinderExt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After emailing pCloud support, I got this answer :

> Yes, this is a behavior that was desired - launching the virtual disk restarts Finder to support it. But we noticed that sometimes he does not want to restart depending on the machine and the OS.
>   These are isolated cases, but we decided to launch the next update without this behavior. I hope very soon we will have it available.

So I´m guessing I just have to wait for the next update...

Meanwhile, I unchecked `launch pCloud when starting the system` inside pCloud app and disable it to the Login Items pane of System Preferences and no more issue !

EDIT : pCloud 3.8 seems to work just fine on Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried logging out & unticking the "Reopen windows when logging back in" option?

Else you may have corrupted user `Caches/Saved Application States`.. you could try removing the content of these folders & rebooting:

`~/Library/Caches`

`~/Library/Saved Application States`

Comment: Just did, same result. Finder quit when opening pCloud